# P2os and rosaria not connecting to Pioneer P3-AT

Tags: ros, p2os-driver, rosaria, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have pioneer **p3-at** robot and a separate laptop with Ubuntu **14.04** and Ros **Indigo** properly installed in it.

I downloaded **p2os** from https://github.com/allenh1/p2os and **rosaria** from https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria.git

I am connecting robot to laptop via **serial(robot) to usb(laptop)** converter with RS-232 cable

But every time I run command

> sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER

Then I logged out and again logged in

> sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/ttyUSB0

> rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0

But I get this error

> shivam@shivam-Inspiron-3542:~$ : rosrun rosaria RosAria

> [ INFO] [1422444061.117081691]: RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyS0]

> Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyS0.

> Syncing 0

> No packet.

> Syncing 0

> No packet.

> Trying to close possible old connection

> Syncing 0

> No packet.

> Syncing 0

> No packet.

> Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.

> Syncing 0

> No packet.

> Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.

> Syncing 0

> No packet.

> Could not connect, no robot responding.

> Failed to connect to robot.

> [ERROR] [1422444067.613784823]: RosAria: ARIA could not connect to robot! (Check ~port parameter is correct, and permissions on port device.)

> [FATAL] [1422444067.613882512]: RosAria: ROS node setup failed...

And when I run **p2os** it shows this

> [ERROR] [1349087058.764888277]: Error reading packet header from robot connection: P2OSPacket():Receive():read():

> .

> .

> [ERROR] [1349087114.446749752]: Error reading packet header from robot connection: P2OSPacket():Receive():read():

> [ERROR] [1349087114.447846009]: p2os setup failed...

> [p2os-1] process has died [pid 12089, exit code 255]

Robot is working properly. I tried it with Aria Library which comes with p3-at.
**Actually robot has windows-7 installed in its onboard pc which I think should not be a problem**
because I am connecting it using the serial port of the robot. And no where it mentions that robot's OS is important

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236426/p2os-and-rosaria-not-connecting-to-pioneer-p3-at/) by [shivam-kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27062/shivam-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you run RosAria or p2os you can specify the port via a `port` parameter. e.g.  `rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0` or `rosrun p2os p2os_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0`.     When you tested it with ARIA, did you alse specify the `/dev/ttyUSB0` as the port (e.g. `demo -rp /dev/ttyUSB0`)?

You can turn off the internal onboard computer with the switch on the side. This will give you extra battery life and prevent any possible interference with anything on that computer also using the serial port.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2016-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shivam-kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27062/shivam-kumar/) on 2016-06-10**:
I am using the port /dev/ttyUSB0, I am supplying it as a parameter in RosAria and p2os both. "Turn Off the on-board computer" - the serial port is on the on-board computer, I think if I turn it off then serial port won't work. Or is there any other serial port inside the robot

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2016-06-10**:
Yes you should use the HOST/SERIAL port on the left side of the robot if you are using an added laptop, that is the connection to the robot's controller.   (Which is also connected to the internal computer as well.)

**Comment by [shivam-kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27062/shivam-kumar/) on 2016-06-10**:
So you mean I need to open the robot's top plate to access the Host Serial Port because I don't See it in P3-AT on the side

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2016-06-10**:
Sorry on the P3AT its on the top, next to TX, RX, STATUS leds, reset button, battery led, etc.  STATUS should show if the controller is ready, communicating to software etc. TX and RX will show if there is any communication through the serial connection.

**Comment by [shivam-kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27062/shivam-kumar/) on 2016-06-10**:
Could you please tell me if I need to give any commands on the robot to connect via serial port. I know you said turn off the onboard computer and I did, but it still could not connect. So we don't need to give any permissions, just connect the serial cable to the robot and run the command on laptop

**Comment by [shivam-kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27062/shivam-kumar/) on 2016-06-10**:
Sir I Know its too many questions? but Sir please, its urgent for me, I have to complete my work in 1 month at my college